# Tablix Return All Values Wildcard

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that I want to filter on multiple parameter inputs(4 total). Currently I am using report parameter inputs to get the desired values from the user and the filter is being performed via the Tablix filters on the table. The problem I am having is that the 4 filters are treated as AND filters so if I want to search by just one parameter it will not return any values because the other 3 are blank. My thought is to use the return all wildcard for Tablix but I can't find what that is. I know with SQL it is just * but in Tablix * replaces the % wildcard. Does anyone know what the ALL wildcard is in Tablix or a better solution to this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to set each filter using `LIKE` as the operator and then comparing it to an expression like this..

```
= "*" & Parameters!myParameterName.Value & "*"
```

If the parameter is blank all records will be returned so only parameters with values will do any filtering.